# Socketio Unexpected end of input

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-chrome, socket.io

I have a question related to SocketIO, NodeJS and javascript. 
I have a client, which should show information in realtime.
I'm using this code to parse JSON object

```
socket.on('message', function(dataString){
        var data=JSON.parse(dataString.replace(/'/g, '"'));
        //..Extra stuff to process the data
}
```

However I got **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**, everytime that the message arrives to the client.

What can I do to avoid this error?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a ')', try this:

```
socket.on('message', function(dataString){
        var data=JSON.parse(dataString.replace(/'/g, '"'));
        //..Extra stuff to process the data
});
```